# Is there a library or reference around showing how to build a Ribbon menu using PyGTK?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, ribbon

Hey there, everyone. A really random question, but I'm looking to get into some GUI programming with Python, specifically with the PyGTK library. I've only ever done GUI programming with Java/Swing, and I'd like to do some independent, personal projects in Python as a way of learning my way around the language, since it's been something that I've wanted to do for a really long time now, and haven't been able to find time for! But I digress...

I'm a fan of the Ribbon Interface introduced by Microsoft. I know that Microsoft introduced recently a library for .NET allowing users to build programs utilizing Ribbon. While I don't really want to learn IronPython *yet*, it's still an option for the future. These projects would be build on Linux, specifically Ubuntu, if that makes a difference.

So, finally, my question is this: Is there a library or reference point anywhere that can show me how to build a Ribbon GUI interface? Thank you for all of the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ribbon like widgets developed as a part of GSC.

- http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2007/08/mono-developer-brings-the-ribbon-interface-to-linux.ars
- http://mono-soc-2007.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/laurent/src/Ribbons/
- http://debackerl.wordpress.com/2007/08/25/soc-ribbons-summary/